# Joomla date/calendar function

Tags: date, joomla

Here is my code, works except inserts . before and after date in input box. Tried removing periods, still lists . before and after date.

```
<?php echo JHTML::_( 'calendar',".$this->start.",'start','start','%m-%d-%Y'); ?>
```

Something must be wrong with the syntax but i cannont figure it out

Joomla 1.6 JHTML

When " and . are removed I get this:

[23-Feb-2012 22:00:11] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::_*construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (02-24-2012) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character' in /mnt/stor9-wc1-dfw1/653320/www.alumnifootballusa.com/web/content/libraries/joomla/utilities/date.php:149
Stack trace:#0 /mnt/stor9-wc1-dfw1/653320/www.alumnifootballusa.com/web/content/libraries/joomla/utilities/date.php(149): DateTime->*_construct('02-24-2012', Object(DateTimeZone))#1/mnt/stor9-wc1-dfw1/653320/www.alumnifootballusa.com/web/content/libraries/joomla/factory.php(452): JDate->__construct('02-24-2012', 'UTC')#2 /mnt/stor9-wc1-dfw1/653320/www.alumnifootballusa.com/web/content/libraries/joomla/html/html.php(573): JFactory::getDate('02-24-2012', 'UTC')#3 [internal function]: JHtml::date('02-24-2012')#4 /mnt/stor9-wc1-dfw1/653320/www.alumnifootballusa.com/web/content/libraries/joomla/html/html.php(187): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)#5 /mnt/stor9-wc1-dfw1/653320/www.alumnifootball in /mnt/stor9-wc1-dfw1/653320/www.alumnifootballusa.com/web/content/libraries/joomla/utilities/date.php on line 149

Comment: This is not a standard PHP function. You need to tell us what application it comes from.

Comment: "Work" and "Wont Work" are not phrases that will get you far on Stackoverflow.

Comment: This is directly related to JHTML framework, and not PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Joomla code?

Try using braces around the PHP entry.

I don't see why the double quotes are there at all, though.

EDIT
Can you show us what your various options have echoed to the page?

Comment: I think you'll have to try your luck in the Joomla forums. This is not standard PHP really. It looks like the format of your output date is wrong. Try YYYY-MM-DD, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JHTML::calendar(date("d-m-Y"),'revdate', 'date', '%d-%m-%Y',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
```

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.